# Can't generate complete data to PDF file in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, itext

I have a `jtable` that i'm using to display some data. Say I have around 200 rows of data. I am able to generate the `pdf`, by using the `iText library`, but the problem i'm facing is that all the rows aren't generated. How can I add a `new page` dynamically so that I generate all the rows? Kindly have  a look at the code below and please help me out here.

```
Document doc = new Document(new Rectangle(1350, 1450));
  PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, 0, 800, 0.50f);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
    String generatedDate = formatter.format(date);try {

        PdfWriter writer;
        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(save_pdf.getSelectedFile().getAbsoluteFile() + ".pdf"));
    writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.PageLayoutSinglePage);

        doc.open();

        PdfAction action = PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(1, pdfDest, writer);
        writer.setOpenAction(action);
        doc.add(new Paragraph("REPORTS", f));

        doc.add(new Paragraph("Document Generated On - " + generatedDate, f));

        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

        cb.saveState();

              Graphics2D g2;

        g2 = cb.createGraphics(1350, 1275);
        Shape oldClip = g2.getClip();
        g2.clipRect(0, 0, 1350, 1275);//1275


        table1.print(g2);
        JTableHeader h = table1.getTableHeader();
        h.print(g2);

        g2.setClip(oldClip);
          writer.newPage();
        g2.dispose();
        cb.restoreState();

    } catch (DocumentException | FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    doc.close();
```

Comment: I'd consider [JasperReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) or even one of the [`JTable#print`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#print()) methods (and print to PDF)

Comment: You could "fake" print the `JTable` through the table's `Printable`, see [`JTable#getPrintable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getPrintable(javax.swing.JTable.PrintMode,%20java.text.MessageFormat,%20java.text.MessageFormat))

Comment: I will certainly go through `Jasper Reports`. But is there no other alternative to it ?Also, I'm not printing the `JTable`. I just need to generate the `Jtable` content to `pdf`.

Comment: You have a `Graphics` context (I'm assuming it's a `java.awt.Graphics`), `Printable` will accept a `Graphics` context, which can do the paging for you

Comment: What do you mean by `Printable` will accept a `Graphics` context ?I just have to generate the `jtable` data to `PDF` format.

Comment: `JTable#getPrintable` returns a [`Printable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/Printable.html) interface, the first method of the [`Printable#print`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/Printable.html#print(java.awt.Graphics,%20java.awt.print.PageFormat,%20int)) methods is a `java.awt.Graphics`, which you (seem) to create using `g2 = cb.createGraphics(1350, 1275);`.  You could utilise this to print each page of the `JTable`.  This is essentially what would happen wehn you try to "print" a `JTable` to a printer

Comment: Can you please provide an example? I am finding it hard to understand it. Also, why do you keep saying print ? I don't require to print the `JTable`. I have to generate the rows into `pdf` using `iText`. But i'm not able to get all the rows. Hence, I need to add a new page to the `pdf` so that I can display the rest of the rows in that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so this is pretty basic example...

`JTable` supports printing already, through it's various `print` methods, basically this boils down to getting an instance of the `JTable` `Printable` interface and passing it off to the print API, which needs a `Graphics2D` context to paint to...

Oddly enough, you have a `Graphics2D` context, so the trick here is to "act" as the printer and call the `JTable`'s `Printable` `print` method yourself...

[image: Pages]

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 10);
for (int row = 0; row < 400; row++) {
    Object[] values = new Object[10];
    for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
        values[col] = ((char) ('A' + col)) + "x" + row;
    }
    model.addRow(values);
}

JTable table = new JTable(model);
table.setSize(table.getPreferredSize());

JTableHeader tableHeader = table.getTableHeader();
tableHeader.setSize(tableHeader.getPreferredSize());

Document doc = new Document(new Rectangle(1350, 1450));
PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, 0, 800, 0.50f);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
String generatedDate = formatter.format(date);

Paper paper = new Paper();
paper.setSize(1350, 1450);
paper.setImageableArea(10, 10, 1350 - 20, 1450 - 20);

PageFormat pf = new PageFormat();
pf.setPaper(paper);

Printable printable = table.getPrintable(JTable.PrintMode.NORMAL, null, null);
try {

    PdfWriter writer;
    writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("test.pdf"));
    writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.PageLayoutSinglePage);

    doc.open();

    // Use this to "test" if there is page
    // available for printing, otherwise it prints
    // a empty page and I can't figure out
    // how to remove it :P
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();

    Font f = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 12f);
    int page = 0;
    int result = Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    do {

        result = printable.print(g, pf, page);

        if (result == Printable.PAGE_EXISTS) {

            cb.saveState();
            Graphics2D g2 = cb.createGraphics(1350, 1450);

            System.out.println(page);
            result = printable.print(g2, pf, page);

            g2.dispose();
            cb.restoreState();

            doc.add(new Paragraph("REPORTS", f));
            doc.add(new Paragraph("Document Generated On - " + generatedDate, f));

            page++;
            doc.newPage();

        }

    } while (result == Printable.PAGE_EXISTS);
    g.dispose();

} catch (DocumentException | PrinterException | FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    doc.close();
}
```

Now, I need to display the table in order to get the row headers to display, but there might be another work around for this.

Comment: Hey thanks ! That worked like a charm and solved my problem. Have a lot to read about the `Printable Interface` and the `JTable#getPrintable` method. :)

Comment: My `iText` is pretty crappy, since we generate reports for PDF, Excel and printer, we just use JasperReports, but that should give you a basic idea

Answer (score 0):

```
PdfAction action = PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(1, pdfDest, writer);
```

Here you use only one page to write the content. So iText can not write the content in next page. **gotoLocalPage** method only acted in only specific page. Please refer the below link and change your code...

[Just gothrough this page](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=99)

Comment: Where do I add `document.newpage()` ? If I remove the statement  `PdfAction action = PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(1,pdfDest,writer);` , then i don't get anything in my `pdf`.