# Eliminating Blank White Space in JTable After Setting Width

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I am trying to set the size of a table in Java.

```
    pTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    pTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(120);
    pTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(100);
```

The table is in the correct position in my frame but there is this unnecessary blank space to the right of the last column. 
This is what I get:

[image]

I would just like to eliminate that blank white space that is to the right of the first name column.

Please don't lock this question, there is a similar one out there but it did not have any info that was of any help to me.

Comment: Don't set the size of the columns? Maybe try using `AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN` instead of `AUTO_RESIZE_OFF`

Comment: I want them to be size because if they aren't they fill up that entire white space and that is much wider than I want my table to be. AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN makes the columns not change sizes at all

Comment: Okay, so which of these two situations is less desirable to you, the white space or the column filling the remaining space?

Comment: Both are undesirable, I just want my table to be less wide and not show this remaining white space. If I had the last column fill the white space it defeats the purpose since I wanted my table to be less wide originally.

Comment: Then consider using a different layout manager - You should consider having a look [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341354/resize-jtable-to-fit-number-of-rows) which will effect the `preferredScrollableViewportSize`, see the up-voted answer and not the accepted answer

Comment: Without sizing the columns, the columns fill the white space proportionately, so all I want to do is make the table less wide without creating that white space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JTable has a predefined preferred size.

You can reset this by doing something like:

```
JTable table = new JTable(5, 2);
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(120);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(100);
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
```

Now the width will be the width of the columns, but of course the height will be the height of all the rows as well.

But if you add the scrollpane to the frame using `BorderLayout.LINE_START` as the constraint, then the width of the table will be preserved and the height will vary with the height of the frame.